# Calculate Mean Kinetic Temperature with Variable Time Interval

Tags: mathematical-physics, temperature

Based on the formula listed (when you have variable intervals) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_kinetic_temperature

What is meant by "t1 to tn are the time intervals"?

In other words, if I take a readings at: 
1475613051 (Tue, 04 Oct 2016 20:30:51 GMT)
1475693051 (Wed, 05 Oct 2016 18:44:11 GMT) 
1475694051 (Wed, 05 Oct 2016 19:00:51 GMT)

What are the values of t1, t2, and t3 supposed to be?

a) t1 = 0; t2 = 1475693051-1475613051 = 80000; t3 = 1475694051-1475693051 = 1000

b) t1 = 1475613051; t2 = 1475693051; t3 = 1475694051

c) something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t_1$ is the period of time during which the average temperature $T_1$ is found.

So you measure the temperature over a period of 10 seconds $t_1$ and find that the average temperature during this time interval is 275 K $T_1$.

Then later you find that the average temperature $T_2$ is 278 K over a period of time (time interval) of 15 seconds $t_2$.

Etc

Comment: thanks.

I'm interested in your answer given **actual** timestamps from a sensor. Say we record temp values at specific times (ts_1, ts_2, ts_3, ...) with values of (v_1, v_2, v_3, ...). So we avoid the simplified formula, let's assume that the sensor takes readings at non-equal intervals.

Are you suggesting that the first interval t_1 would be ts_2 - ts_1 in length having an average temperature of (v_1 + v_2) / 2?

The second interval would be ts_3 - ts_2 in length having an average temperature of (v_2 + v_3) / 2?

Comment: The time interval $t_n$ is a weighting factor.  A larger time interval means that the average temperature measured in that interval has a larger influence on the value of the average.

Comment: Ok. Let's say our starting temperature is 200K (T0), after 5 mins (t1), we get a reading of 212K (T1). What's the corresponding temperature for t1? Is it (T1 -T0)/2 = 206K? Or is it just T1 = 212K? @Farcher

Comment: @ ZinoHu I have found a paper for you which I hope you will find answers all your questions including giving an idea of the errors involved.   What you need starts at section 4 "A computational equation for MKT" although the preamble is eminently readable.  https://www.academia.edu/19390751/A_computational_procedure_for_mean_kinetic_temperature_using_unequally_spaced_data

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that makes sense to me is that you have to consider average temperatures over certain time intervals. That means that $T_i$ is the average temperature in the the $i$th time interval of duration $t_i$.

[This](http://supa.pharmacy.bg.ac.rs/assets/9219) and [this](http://www.sensitech.com/assets/articles/mktapopapergalley13april2009.pdf) source only use the simplified version for equal intervals, but they also refer to averge intervals.